# Prevent keyboard input but allow automatic scanner input on textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

Hello everyone I'm using a RFID scanner that puts the scanned code in whatever text field available at scanning time. For instance, it could put the text inside a cell in Excel or in the address bar of a web browser.

I made an application with a textbox that receives the input sent by the scanner, but I want to disable user-input (keyboard). I tried setting the textbox property "read only" to true, but then the text is not displayed in the textbox.

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: By "available", do you mean whatever input has current focus?

Comment: That is correct. Sorry for my english

Comment: I have a feeling you are not going to be able to do this easily - the scanner likely appears as a keyboard. You will probably need to get into the Win API for this, so you can differentiate devices.

Comment: I was afraid of that. But thanks anyway

Comment: Can you configure the device to prefix the characters it sends; just like most barcode scanners?

Comment: Can you configure the scanner to send to a COM port?  It's been a few years but the Symbol scanners I used to program had this option.

Comment: Yes, I can prefix the characters. I'm not sure about the COM port. This is the documentation page of the scanner http://www.socketmobile.com/support/downloads/data-collection/series6/?page=Detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most barcode scanners are just keyboard input. This would could be done via intercepting HID calls or intercepting key press events in the input box. I wouldn't expect that to work well, but good luck.

Comment: Several barcode scanners (Symbol in my experience) have a method to treat the input as a COM port.

Comment: I've never had an experience with any of those, at least where I knew that setting existed. That might make the experience easier if it's not registered as a HID.