# Control to allow barcode scanner input, but ignore keyboard input

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I am using a barcode scanner in my WinForms application. Using this scanner the user can scan barcodes,  and that value will be entered in a TextBox. I then process this TextBox's value.

Its works perfectly, but the user can also enter arbitrary text in the TextBox.

Is there any way to prevent this? Or can I modify my TextBox such that it only accepts values from the scanner, and not from the keyboard?

```
    private void txtBarcode_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
           if (txtbarcode.Text != "")
               if (rdbScan.Checked == true)
                {
                    string TEXTVALUE = this.txtbarcode.Text.ToString();
                    try
                    {
                        string abc = TEXTVALUE.Substring(0, 3);
                        if (abc == "]C1")
                        {
                            this.txtbarcode.Text = this.txtbarcode.Text.Remove(0, 3);

                        }
                        strRsnText = this.txtbarcode.Text;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return;

                    }
                }

                if (strRsnText.ToString().Trim() != "")
                {
                    lblScannedbarcode.Text = "Scanned value is :" + strRsnText;

                  }

                  // Calling  Some Function Here

           }
```

Comment: most of the bar code devices work as a keyboard, that is why they work without a separate driver, hence it might prove difficult.

Comment: Display the text in a label instead of a textbox.

Textboxes generally infer user input. Labels are read-only.

Comment: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482312/prevent-keyboard-input-but-allow-automatic-scanner-input-on-textbox

Comment: I would suggest using some sort of input validation. A regular expression or some other custom code should do the trick. Do you have an example of what could be considered "valid" input?

Comment: generally i am scanning GS128 Barcode , SSCCC Barcode, and its contains value some time numerical or Alphabetical